Не приходит код потдверждения Telethon
У меня был утром полностью рабочий код я обновлял его поэтому моментами мог авторизиваться и снова выйти, но при повторной авторизации он без проблем отправлял мне код, в один момент этот код попросту перестал доходить может есть у кого идеи или кто может быть уже сталкивался с подобным?
    elif event.data == b'add_account':
    async with bot.conversation(event.sender_id) as conv:
        await conv.send_message('Введите номер для регистрации')
        phone_number = await conv.get_response()

        await conv.send_message('Отправка кода на указанный номер...')
        await start_login_process(user_id, phone_number.text, conv)

async def start_login_process(user_id, phone_number, conv):
session_name = f"{phone_number}.session"
client = TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash)
await client.connect()

try:

    if not await client.is_user_authorized():
        await client.send_code_request(phone_number)
        await conv.send_message('Введите код из сообщения')
        code = await conv.get_response()
        await client.sign_in(phone_number, code)
        session_str = client.session.save()  # Сохранение сессии
        random_session = session_generate()
        add_account(user_id, phone_number, "True", random_session)  # Добавляем подтвержденный аккаунт
        await conv.send_message('Аккаунт успешно добавлен')
except PhoneNumberInvalidError:
    await conv.send_message('Код подтверждения устарел. Пожалуйста, запросите новый код и попробуйте снова.')
except Exception as e:
    await conv.send_message(f'Ошибка при добавлении аккаунта: {str(e)}')
finally:
    await client.disconnect()

